# env-cmd throwing error even with -f applied

Tags: env-cmd

I'm have env-cmd installed locally on a windows 10 setup. Calling `env-cmd -f .env.local` returns the error:

`Error: Failed to find .env file at default paths: [./.env,./.env.js,./.env.json]`

I even installed the library in to my app and run it from the `./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd` and got the same error.